# Importing from com.android.server

Tags: android, android-studio

Hi I'm trying to write a little code with android studio and I want to use the **LightsManager** from `com.android.server.lights.LightsManager.`

Is there any way to **import** `com.android.server package`?

Comment: there is no such class in the SDK: `com.android.server.lights.LightsManager`, so no, you cannot use it

Comment: i see it here but OK.. is there an option to do it with any other class of com.android.server?